# REACT, NODE, EXPRESS Error when connect to API

Tags: reactjs, api, express, endpoint

I get errors:

```
localhost/:1 Failed to load http://localhost:5000/api/hello: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This is my asynchronously POST:

```
async function submitToServer(data){

  try{
      let response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/hello', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-type' :  'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        return responseJson;
  }   catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
  }
}
```

And this is my server:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

What should I do to send this information to the API?
Do I need to create an endpoint or something?

So I installed `cors npm`.
Now I have these errors:

> POST localhost:5000/api/hello 404 (Not Found)

and

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

What can I do now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Comment: Is this the same as my answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543641/express-route-index-js-not-working-in-my-react-app/50543922#50543922?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning JSON from your express server.

```
res.send({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
```

should be

```
res.json({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
```

Also, you defined the route for `GET`, yet you sending a `POST` request. So your handler should be:

```
app.post('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
});
```

Comment: Still. StepOneValidationForm.js:42 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Ok how now i can display this data?

Comment: Ask a new question.